# MySQL alternative select query

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to select list of discounts for a specified customer, but only include one highest discount out of a product group if part number is specified for that item by a customer.

```
Customers table:
id      name
1226    ESPRESSO SPECIALTY FOODS
1227    ESSROC   ACCOUNTING SERVICES
1228    EVAPAR
```

Discounts table:

```
prod_code_id    part_num    account_id  multiplier
123               28H57    1228         0.75
123                        1228         0.8
303                        1228         0.65
```

Items Table:

```
prod_code_id    item    description price
123            28h57    Oil         50.00
123            0072     HOSE        62.31
123             0147    BOLT        0.98
303            0147     BOLT        1.39
303             0211    HEX SOCKET  1.86
```

This is what I'm trying to do

```
SELECT 

  items.item,
  items.description,
  items.price,
  discounts.multiplier
FROM items
LEFT JOIN 
    (
        SELECT multiplier,prod_code_id
        FROM ".$type."_discounts 

        WHERE account_id='".$_POST['accountId']."'
        ORDER BY part_num collate utf8_general_ci LIKE '%".$_POST['searchPart']."%' DESC

    ) AS discounts ON items.prod_code_id=discounts.prod_code_id

WHERE items.item collate utf8_general_ci LIKE '%".$search_word."%'
LIMIT 8
```

So lets say i have a part number that has special discount in a subquery I enter:

```
SELECT prod_code_id, part_num, account_id,multiplier
    FROM customers_discounts 
    WHERE account_id=1228
ORDER BY part_num collate utf8_general_ci LIKE '%28h57%' DESC
```

on the output I'm getting

```
prod_code_id    part_num    account_id  multiplier
123             28H57           1228         0.75
123                             1228         0.8
303                             1228         0.65
```

When i only want to get

```
prod_code_id    part_num    account_id  multiplier
123                 28H57       1228        0.75
303                             1228         0.65
```

On the other hand if part number is not specified or does not have special discount i want to have:

```
prod_code_id    part_num    account_id  multiplier
123                              1228      0.8
303                              1228      0.65
```

MYSQL FIDDLE LINK:
[MYSQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/af3abd/1)

Comment: The formatting is driving me crazy :)

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/ <- Go on and make a fiddle for it and I bet you'll get your answer ;-)

Comment: Consider providing proper DDLs and/or an sqlfiddle TOGETHER WITH THE DESIRED RESULT.

Comment: Just added Mysql Fiddle to it, it shows that it selects duplicate discounts now.
I want to only select group discount if no part number specified or it doesnt match records.

Comment: Can anyone help please?